# How to configure 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If I want to redirect my old shop domain http://shop.example.net/product-name.html to http://example.net/product-category/product-new-name

What I should do?

Already doing

```bash
Redirect 301 /Hoodies_c_70.html http://example.net/product-category/apparel/hoodies/
```

but it is not working. it is showing http://example.net/Hoodies_c_70.html

Comment: do you need to redirect Hoodies_c_70.html page or all domain ? i mean you want to redirect site.com/dir/dir/  to newsite.com/newdir/newdir ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. the problem was happening bcoz of this line in .htaccess:

```bash
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/store
```

So I remove that and unchanged other redirect in htaccess. Then add a index.php file with code

```php
header("Location: http://example.com/store/", true, 301);
```

Now everything is good.